# Laravel 4: Nest view inside layout with data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm writing a simple app which only relies on a few routes and views. I've setup an overall layout and successfully nested a template using the following.

**routes.php**

```
View::name('layouts.master', 'master');
$layout = View::of('master');

Route::get('/users', function() use ($layout)
{
    $users = Users::all()
    return $layout->nest('content','list-template');
});
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<h1>Template</h1>
<?=$content?>
```

**list-template.php**

```
foreach($users as $user) {
   echo $user->title;
}
```

How do I pass the query results **$users** into my master template and then into list-temple.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`->nest` allows a 3rd argument for an array of data:

```
   Route::get('/users', function() use ($layout)
    {
        $users = Users::all()
        return $layout->nest('content','list-template', array('users' => $users));
    });
```

Also in your master.blade.php file - change it to this:

```
<h1>Template</h1>
@yield('content')
```

list-template.blade.php   <- note the blade filename:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<?php
  foreach($users as $user) {
     echo $user->title;
   }
?>
@stop
```

Comment: Thanks kindly. however I now have the following error. "Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\View\View::nest() must be of the type array, object given. Called in routes.php"

Comment: I've edited it to pass an array as the third argument rather than an object, which should resolve that error

Comment: Actually that edit needs peer-review. You can change `$users` to `array('users' => $users)` in that third parameter of the `nest()` method: `return $layout->nest('content','list-template', array('users' => $users));`